# Contar elementos de una lista en otra

Tags: python, lista

Tengo dos listas de Python, ambas tienen la misma cantidad de elementos. (todos los elementos son enteros positivos)

Sea:

```
listaUno = [1,2,3,4]
listaDos = [0,3,2,5]
```

Mi función debe recibir estas dos listas y devolver la cantidad de veces que se repite un elemento de una lista en la otra.

Por ejemplo, en el caso anterior la función debe devolver 2 (porque ambas listas comparten el 2 y el 3) No importa si los elementos están en distintas posiciones en las listas.

Comment: Agrega un poco de tu codigo en donde tienes el error para que la comiunidad te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = 0
for i in set(listaUno):
    result += list(set(listaDos)).count(i)
return result
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Las publicaciones que son sólo código no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios y se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace ese código? ¿cómo soluciona el problema? Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Existe un método en los `sets` que encuentra la intersección entre dos de ellos. La idea sería la siguiente:

```
set1={a,b,c,d}
set2={a,f,d,e}

set1.intersection(set2)  # Nos daría {a,d}
```

Por lo que partiendo de tus listas:

```
listaUno = [1,2,3,4]
listaDos = [0,3,2,5]
```

podrías hacerlo así:

```
set(listaUno).intersection(set(listaDos))  # Devolvería {2, 3}
```

Puesto que lo que quieres es la cantidad de veces, con un `len` lo obtendrías:

```
len(set(listaUno).intersection(set(listaDos)))  # Devolvería 2
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

una solución es tener 2 bucles `for` uno dentro de otro y que se comparen los elementos.

```
listaUno = [1,2,3,4]
listaDos = [0,3,2,5]

def function(listaUno, listaDos):
    contador=0
    for i in listaUno:
        for j in listaDos:
            if i == j:
                print("Coincide el valor %s" % j)
                contador += 1
    print("La cantidad que se repiten es de:",contador)



function(listaUno,listaDos)
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu comentario!